# Latexindent doesn't work without sudo

Tags: mac, latexindent

When i run `latexindent -v` I get: `segmentation fault  latexindent -v`

With `sudo latexindent -v`: `3.8, 2020-03-21`

I installed latex indent with `sudo tlmgr install latexindent` because without it I would get: `You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2020basic/tlpkg/ is not writable.`

It doesn't work in VSCode either, the path is set up good. I guess it's because it calls `latexindent` without `sudo`.

Comment: What are the permissions on latexindent? The file should have permissions rwxr-xr-x so it should be executable by anyone.

Comment: @HerbSchulz The file at `/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent` has `rwxr-x-rx` permissions.

Comment: How about the link in `/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/bin/x86-Darwin`?

Comment: It also has `rwxr-xr-x` permissions

Comment: It sounds like this is a permissions thing, rather than being specific to latexindent. When you installed texlive did you do so as sudo....?

Comment: See the details in this answer about changing permission: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459/6621

Comment: What do `which latexindent` and `echo $PATH` return?

Comment: @HerbSchulz for latexindent its `/Library/TeX/texbin/latexindent` and the path variable contains the `/Library/TeX/texbin` directory

Comment: @cmhughes I installed it via `brew cask install`. Tried this `sudo chown -R yourusername /usr/local/texlive/2020` and reinstalled the package but still get segmentation fault.